Flask app running with Gunicorn and Nginx via Docker Compose serves / but returns 404 for other routes
Issue:
I am trying to serve a Flask app (running with Gunicorn) via Nginx. My project is set up with containers and orchestrated using Docker Compose. I have edited the nginx.conf to serve my application.
The problem I am facing is that I can access the / route of my Flask application, but when I try to navigate to any other link within the application, I receive a 404 Not Found error.
Nginx Logs
nginx-1  | 172.25.0.1 - - [22/May/2024:15:57:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5086 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0"

nginx-1  | 2024/05/22 15:57:49 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/dataset_detail/1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /dataset_detail/1?page=1 HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0/"

nginx-1  | 172.25.0.1 - - [22/May/2024:15:57:49 +0000] "GET /dataset_detail/1?page=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://0.0.0.0/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0"

nginx.conf
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        # Serve static files directly if possible
        location /static {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
        }
        # Additional static file directories
        location /docs {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/docs;
            index index.html;
        }
        location /dataset {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dataset;
            autoindex on;
        }
        # Handle Flask app routes
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @flask;
        }
        location @flask {
            proxy_pass http://app:5000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_request_body on;
        }
    }
}

Additional Info

The root route / of my Flask application works correctly and returns the expected page.
Other routes, like /dataset_detail/1, return a 404 Not Found error.
It appears that Nginx is attempting to serve these routes from the /usr/share/nginx/html directory instead of passing the requests to the Flask application.

Question:
What could be causing Nginx to serve the root route correctly but return a 404 error for other routes? How can I configure Nginx to correctly forward all requests to the Flask application?

The issue is that, by default, nginx location blocks uses a "prefix match" strategy.
From the docs:

A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression. Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching). To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.

So, location /dataset is matching the requests to /dataset_detail/1, looking for the static file and returning a 404 when it's not found.
I'm not sure what the best solve is for your particular application but you might be able to use a location regex matcher to more accurately detect known/good static files or possibly use try_files to redirect to @flask if a static file is not found.
